# ASP.NET Core 3.0 SPA in an endless redirection loop

Tags: lazy-loading, single-page-application, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, angular-http-interceptors

If I create a new project using aspnet core 3.0 SPA template, everything is  okay. But when i copy the Api-Authorization folder to use the `AuthorizeInterceptor`, `AuthorizeService` and guard, For an unknown reason, when I login, the login succeed but `login-menu` still shows me the option to login again. When I set a route guard as `AuthorizeGuard`, then I fall into an endless redirection loop.

How to solve this?

PS. I just noticed that when I stop using hash in my routes, everything works as wished `RouterModule.forRoot(routes/*, { useHash: true }*/)]`.

Answer (score 0):

After 48hours searching, I realised that `ApiAuthorization` works only with Html5 links and not with hash. so I had to remove the useHash in `AppRoutingModule` like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes/*, { useHash: true }*/)]
```

Now everything works correctly